# HTML CSS Kendo Slide-In Sticks out too far when open

Tags: html, jquery, css, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo-UI Slide-In that sticks out too far when it's open. When I modify it to be along the page edge, the handle disappears. I've modified every element and swapped things around countless times, but I just end up cancelling out anything that I've done.

I know the culprit probably has to do with slidebarcol but I don't know how to fix it.

I've been banging my head on the wall for too many days trying to fix this thing. I've googled for hours, read the Kendo FAQ, and tried to find other examples. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here's the link to the example I used on the Kendo site: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/fx/slidein

Here's the full html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="background:#656565;overflow-x: hidden;">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="kendo.all.min.js"></script>


    <div id="example">
        <div id="slide-in-content">

            <div class="slidebartable">
                <div class="slidebarcol" id="sidebarcol2" >
                    <div id="slidebar" class="open">
                        <div id="slidebarcontainer">
                            <a href="" class="rotate" id="slide-in-handle-rotate">
                                <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;">NEED HELP?</span>
                                <span style="font-size: 16px; font-style: italic;">&emsp;&emsp;Click to Expand</span>
                            </a>
                            <div id="slidebarinstructions" class="instructions">
                                <br />Instructions here.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var slide = kendo.fx($("#slidebar")).slideIn("right"),
            visible = true;

        $("#slidebarcontainer").click(function (e) {
            if (visible) {
                slide.reverse();
            } else {
                slide.play();
            }
            visible = !visible;
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    </script>
    <style>
        html {
            font-size: 14px;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        .slidebartable {
            width: 100%;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }

        .slidebarcol {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            z-index: 5;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        #slidebar {
            right: -8px;
            height: 351px;
            background-color: #fff;
            position: relative;
            border-radius: 12px 0 0 12px;
            -moz-border-radius: 12px 0 0 12px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 12px 0 0 12px;
            border-right: 0;
            margin-right: -363px;
            top: 155px;
        }

        html >/**/ body #slidebar {
            right: -0px\9;
        }

        #slidebar.open {
            width: 400px;
            box-shadow: -3px 3px 3px 0px #999;
            -moz-box-shadow: -3px 3px 3px 0px #999;
            -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 3px 3px 0px #999;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
            -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
            -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
            transition-duration: 0.3s;
        }

        #slidebar.collapse {
            width: 26px;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
            -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
            -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
            transition-duration: 0.3s;
            display: block;
            background-color: transparent;
        }

        #slidebarcontainer > a.rotate {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #004b87;
        }

        #slidebar .instructions {
            margin-left: 40px;
            margin-right: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            height: 300px;
            overflow: auto;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-family: Helvetica;
        }

        #slide-in-handle-rotate {
            position: absolute;
            top: 160px;
            left: -162px;
            border-radius: 0px 0px 11px 11px;
            padding: 5px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 341px;
            font-size: 15px;
            background-color: #9ac040;
            -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
            transform: rotate(90deg);
            white-space: nowrap;
            position: absolute;
            color: #004b87;
        }
    </style>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help or direction you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

There are probably several solutions, but this one is what worked for me.

```
<div id="slidebarinstructions" class="instructions">
    <br />Instructions here.
</div>
```

Becomes:

```
<div id="slidebar" class="open white-space">
    <br />Instructions here.
</div>
```

Changed #slidebar right: -8px to -29px.

And added this:

```
        #slidebar .white-space {
            right: -29px !important;
            top: 0px !important;
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-right: 10px;
            border-radius: 0;
            box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px #999;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px #999;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px #999;
        }
```